# Android Tensorflow Lite 2.9.0 AAR InterpreterAPI not found Error

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, aar, tflite

As per our requirement, I want to add TF Lite AAR file into our project.

So I have downloaded AAR file(2.9.0) from [Maven](https://jarcasting.in/artifacts/org.tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/2.9.0/) and added to my project.Then I can imports the Interpreter and other required things, but when I try to build and run the project I’m getting InterpreterAPI class not found error like this.([please refer the screenshots][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPMkM.png)[[3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj9JY.png)) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgUom.png) [[5]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Ddj.png)

**class file for org.tensorflow.lite.InterpreterApi not found**

If I add below 2.7.0 version aar files, I’m able to build and run the projects but those are deprecated, I want use latest AAR file only.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Note: I should use AAR only not gradle dependencies

here the code

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUp();
    try {
        interpreter = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("errrrr........." + ex);
    }
    csvDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    readCSV("stats1.csv");
    Button predict_button = findViewById(R.id.predict_button);
    predict_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        try {
            doInference();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("errrrr......predcition..." + ex);
        }
    });
}

private void doInference() {
    if (interpreter != null) {
        float[][] output = new float[2128][1];
        interpreter.run(inputList, output);
    System.out.println("output size...." + output.length);
        print2D(output);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Interpreter is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {

    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("imei.tflite"); // u can place ur model here

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declareLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declareLength);
}
```

Comment: as u said, I have added my code snippet, please check and let me know, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added one more aar file i.e **tensorflow-lite-api.aar** along with **tensorflow-lite.aar**

After adding this aar to the libs floder, I'm able to build and run my project.

here the [maven link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-api/2.9.0/)